# HTML dynamic content mysteriously dissapperars

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui, monaca

I am currently working on a hybrid mobile application using Monaca, Cordova and Onsen-UI, but my problem seems more javascript-related.

I want to dynamically create list of items. For this purpouse I created simple page template, here is the key section:

```
<ons-list id="transaction-list"></ons-list>

    <script id="transaction-list-item" type="text/template">
        <ons-list-item class="transaction-item-detail" >
            <div class="left transaction-party">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="center transaction-amount">{{amount}}</div>
            <div class="center transaction-state" style="margin-left: 1em">{{state}}</div>
            <div class="right">
                <ons-icon icon="ion-chevron-right"></ons-icon>
            </div>
        </ons-list-item>
    </script>
```

The idea behind this code snippet is to somehow get data, and for each Object take the script part, replace variable parts with actual data and insert it into *transaction-list* element. This logic is implemented using following javascript function:

```
function showRequests()  {
    var requests = storage.requests;
    document.querySelector('#transaction-list').innerHTML=requests.map(function(item){
        return document.querySelector('#transaction-list-item').innerHTML
            .replace('{{amount}}', item.amount).replace('{{name}}', item.reciever[0].fullName)
            .replace('{{state}}', item.state.stateName);
    }).join('');

};
```

This works as a charm, and I get generated List filled with items I keep in *storage*, result is following:
[image: Correctly initialized list of items]
**Now here comes the twist!**
I go over several another pages and return back to this page, and out of nowhere, my list is empty. No worries, I think, lets look to console what is happening. Since my list seems without content, using jQuery I log content of the list:

```
        console.log(document.querySelector('#transaction-list'));
```

and the result is following:
[image]
This seems, that the list I queried should have the expected content. But when I inspect the element, it really appears to be empty:

[image]

I simply cannot wrap my head around this blunder. I would really appreciate any help from more skilled fellow programmers! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you fill in the list and how you move through the pages. 
If you don't fill in the list on the initialization of your page that contains it, it might be possible that when you go back to this page, you're actually creating a new one. Thus the old page still exists with the filled list as your log says, but as you go back to your page you are viewing a new one page where the current list is not new.

My advice is to either call the function on the initialization of the page (see snippet below), or post more details about how you move through the pages in order to see the problem.

Calling function on the initialization of a page:

```
document.addEventListener('init', function(event) {

      if(event.target.matches('#page_id')){
        showRequests();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the pattern for moving through pages: ons-navigator. I poorly managed the stack of pages, which caused this unexpected fault. 
After reseting the page stack of ons-navigator, everything loades as should.

Thanks everyone for their time spent with this issue.